# PHP's preg_match_all() to pull out all php tags

Tags: php, regex

I have a large set of HTML files that I need to parse the `<? and ?>` tags out of, keeping in mind `<?xml` and the fact that an opening `<?php` tag doesn't need an ending tag... EOF counts too.

My regular expression knowledge is admittedly lacking: `/<\?[^(\?>)]*\?>/`

---

Example HTML:

```
<? 
function trans($value) {
  // Make sure it does not translate the function call itself
}
?>
<!-- PHP 

code -->
<div id='test' <?= $extraDiv ?>>
<?= trans("hello"); ?>
<? if ($something == 'hello'): ?>
<? if ($something == 'hello'): ?>
<p>Hello</p>
<? endif; ?>
<?php

// Some multiline PHP stuff
echo trans("You are \"great'"); // I threw some quotes in to toughen the test
echo trans("Will it still work with two");
echo trans('and single quotes');
echo trans("multiline

stuff
");

echo trans("from array('test')",array('test'));

$counter ++;

?>

<p>Smart <?= $this->translation ?> time</p>
<p>Smart <?=$translation ?> time</p>
<p>Smart <?= $_POST['translation'] ?> time</p>

</div>

<?
trans("This php tag has no end");
```

---

Hoped for Array:

```
[0] => "<? 
function trans($value) {
  // Make sure it does not translate the function call itself
}
?>",
[1] => "<?= $extraDiv ?>",
[2] => etc...
```

Comment: The correct way to do this is with `token_get_all`. Sorry, I don't have time now to put an answer together...

Comment: Do you know if this accounts for opening/closing tags found in strings?

Comment: If it would be parsed as an opening tag if it was just in a PHP file, it is parsed as one by `token_get_all`. So `"foo <? a"` would not be matched by this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that isn't how character classes work. Luckily you don't need to worry about that because we can use a `?` to make the character class non-greedy. I'll also add a `s` to the end so that `.` can also match newlines, it usually can't.

```
/<\?(.*?)\?>/s
```

Comment: This `/<\?.*?(?:\?>|$)/s` ended up doing what I needed. Thanks so much for putting me on the right track... I knew a negative group was overcomplicating things. :P

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're looking for is lookahead and lookbehind.  These regex operators basically allow you to include text in the search but omit it from the final result.

So first, you'd want to change your regex to this:

```
'/(?<=\<\?)[^(\?\>)]*(?=\?\>)/'
```

For EOF, you'd use the $ symbol.  Therefore:

```
'/(?<=\<\?)[^(\?\>)]*(?=\?\>|$)/'
```

I haven't tested this but I think that should do what you're looking for, or at very least point you in the right direction.