# preg_match_all() php tags that aren't inside quotes

Tags: php, regex

This question is Part 2 of [PHP's preg_match_all() to pull out all php tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423815/phps-preg-match-all-to-pull-out-all-php-tags)

I need to extend this regex `/<\?.*?(?:\?>|$)/s` to not match when it finds tags inside single or double quotes. This will involve back-referencing the matched quote type, which goes beyond my intuitive understanding of regex.

---

Example HTML:

```
<?
  // Test xml
  $this->_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
  $this->_xml .= "<TransferredValueTxn xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" >\n";
  $this->_xml .= "<?=$test?>    <TransferredValueTxnReq>" . trans("test") . "\n";
?>
```

---

Hoped for Result:

```
[0] => "<?
  // Test xml
  $this->_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
  $this->_xml .= "<TransferredValueTxn xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" >\n";
  $this->_xml .= "<?=$test?>    <TransferredValueTxnReq>" . trans("test") . "\n";
?>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: `/<\?(?:.*?(?:(\"|').*?[^\\]\1)*)*(?:\?>|$)/s`

Work perfectly with all of my unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use PHP to parse PHP, you may want to try using the [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) function. It'll do a lot of the work for you, using the same engine that PHP uses to parse code that it's running.

Comment: I'm not positive, but as far as I can tell `token_get_all()` doesn't parse HTML with inline PHP. Which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It should! Note that it'll only recognize `<?` if you have short tags enabled, though, just like the "real" interpreter.